# Detecting private IP addresses using one member in the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, networking

Is there **one** method or property in the .NET Framework that tells if an [IP address is private](http://www.duxcw.com/faq/network/privip.htm)? Or must a custom check be coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for IPv6 addresses with the IPAddress.IsIPv6SiteLocal property.  You'll have to cook your own for IP4.

Comment: Does this IP6 method mean the same as private IP address? MSDN docs don't specify http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.isipv6sitelocal(VS.80).aspx